# mkdir Command Not Found in shell script within if loop

Tags: shell, command, mkdir

I have simple script below,

```
if [ ! -e $c ];
then
mkdir "$c"
fi
```

$c is containing the folder path. I got the error mkdir: command not found. please help me out.

Thanks in advance.
Navdeep

Answer (score 13, accepted):

can you run `mkdir` in your login session?

If you can, most probably the problem is caused by PATH in your script, try suing full path:

```
if [ ! -e $c ];
then
/bin/mkdir -p "$c"
fi
```

or export PATH first

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
export PATH
if [ ! -e $c ];
then
/bin/mkdir -p "$c"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it worked. I have wasted my 3 hours on that only. thanks again.

Comment: I faced the same problem. Then i found that i've written `readonly PATH="$OPTARG"` in my script and the exported `PATH` variable in .bash_profile is being overwritten. so mkdir command is not found. Very bad, I should be more careful to set variable.